# How can I pass parts of a list to different variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Is it possible to pass parts of a list to multiple variables to create new lists? I  have a list with 12 words and I want to take the first 4 words and place them in a new list and so on until I have all the words new lists containing 4 words each.

```
sample1 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
print(sample1)
row1, row2, row3 = sample1
print(row1)
print(row2)
print(row3)
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

My desired final result would be:

```
row1 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
row2 = ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
row3 = ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

Comment: Is it always exactly 12 words, or can it be any multiple of 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
sample1 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']

row1, row2, row3 = sample1[0:4], sample1[4:8], sample1[8:12]

print(row1, row2, row3)
```

result:

```
['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'] ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'] ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```

Answer (score 2):

Just split your list with a proper *stepping*:

```
sample1 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
row1, row2, row3 = [sample1[i:i+4] for i in range(0, len(sample1), 4)]
print(row1, row2, row3)
# ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g'] ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k'] ['l', 'm', 'n', 'o']
```